# How to write nested Graph API request

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to create nested FB Graph API request to get images for public event.
The full JSON object is given at this gist: https://gist.github.com/ZeKoU/be92b88440a6ca3d6be3

What I am trying to do is to get only data.0.images object, i.e. I want to get first object from data , then to get images array, and then to pick some fields from there (source for example).

However, all my attempts (see picture below) are returning only two fields for each object inside data field.

[image: Don't know how to get images for first data object...]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Not sure what you're trying to do, but from what I understood the query

```
/310897782446456?fields=photos.fields(id,images{source}).limit(1)
```

should be an example of getting the first photo, extract only some fields from the object (`id` and `images` for example), and then get a single field (`source` for example) from the images array's objects.

- https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=310897782446456%3Ffields%3Dphotos.fields(id%2Cimages%7Bsource%7D).limit(1)&version=v2.3

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.3#fieldexpansion

Comment: Yes, this is correct. I was able to fetch source and width from the images. Thanks a lot..